# How to insert UIProgressView in UITableViewCell that is same width as the cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                                 reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

  //set the cell's text....

  UIProgressView *prg =[[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
  prg.tag = indexPath.row + 1000;
  prg.frame = CGRectMake(0, (cell.frame.size.height - prg.frame.size.height), cell.frame.size.width, 10);

  [prg setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:68/255.0 green:183/255.0 blue:104/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
  [cell addSubview:prg];

  return cell;
}
```

This works on the iPhone - the progress view is the same width as the cell, but on the iPad (this is a universal app), it's only half as wide as the cell.  How do I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using autolayout your best to try avoid frames as much as possible.

To add the progress view to the cell you'll want something along the lines of:

```
// Edit: add the view to the superview first
[cell.contentView addSubview:prg];

prg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

// set width to match the superviews width
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[progressView]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:@{@"progressView":prg}]];

// you don't need to set the height for a UIProgressView, it will default to 2pts I think
```

You'll want to put this where it will be called only once, you will also only want to create your progress view once currently the progressView is created anytime that cell is shown so if that cell is reused X amount of times the progressView will be created X amount of times. .

Comment: I'm getting this when I try that:  Unable to parse constraint format: Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
|[progressView]|

Comment: @croceldon before you can add constraints you must add the subView. [cell.contentView addSubview:prg];

Answer (score 0):

Make it autoresize:

```
prg.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: I'm using auto layout, will this still work ok with constraints?

Comment: It should if you add a `prg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES`. Alternatively, `[cell addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[prg]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(prg)]];` might do the trick.